# Universe: mass = length

Tags: universe

Has there been a moment, where the diameter/radius of the universe in Planck lenghts matched the mass in Planck masses (dark + baryonic)?

Comment: Based on current observations, there is no radius or diameter of the entire universe, since it seems to be infinite. However, if we constrain this question to the **observable** universe, we could probably answer it.

Comment: I o wonder how reliable any estimates might be given the extremes of conditions assumptions would have to be made.

Comment: It seems that the moment is ahead of us. I want to see, if the Sciama's formula for G works out exactly at some point in time G = c^2/sum(all masses in universe)/radius o universe) = mass/radius of universe = 1/1. It should hold true a few billion years away from now, I just want a confirmation.